# Geckofx45 C# Não funciociona em outro computador

Tags: c#

Instalei o gecko no meu visual studio!
no meu pc ele funciona normalmente.

ja tentei enviar para um amigo meu e para meu pc virtual
mais nao funciona da o erro do print. Ambos tinham as dependencias do .NET
tanto é que removendo o gecko do aplicacao o formulario abre normalmente

no print tem o meu pc e o pc virtual!
no meu pc abriu o formulario, no pc virtual deu o erro

```
public FormLogin()
    {
        var programDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        Xpcom.Initialize(Path.Combine(programDirectory, "Firefox"));
        InitializeComponent();
        //MessageBox.Show(Path.Combine(programDirectory, "Firefox"));            
    }
```

dependencias
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Citação

gecko tem alguma dependencia alem destas ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nunca usei geckofx, mas se funcionar como o Selenium pode ser devido a simplesmente não ter o Firefox instalado na máquina

Comment: tambem pensei que poderia ser isso amigo, mais ja tentei instalar o firefox e o problema persiste, obrigado por ajudar!